# Set different width for each column in highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I need to set different widths for each column in my graph... The width is depends on yaxis value... For example if yaxis value is 23 the width of column with this value will be 50px and value need to be in the middle of the column. And if yaxis value is 234 : the width must be 70px and value in the middle of the column... How i can do this?
My graph is:

```
options = {
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'chart',
        type: 'column',
        width: 450
    },

    title: {
        text: 'A glance overview at your contest’s status'
    },

    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Approved Photos', 'Pending Approval Photos', 'Votes', 'Entrants'],
        labels: {
            //rotation: -45,
            style: {
                font: 'normal 9px Verdana, sans-serif, arial'
            }
        }
    },

    yAxis: {
        allowDecimals: false,
        min: 0,
        title: {
            text: 'Amount'
        }
    },

    legend: {
        enabled: false
    },

    series: []
};

series = {
    name: "Amount",
    data: [],
    dataLabels: {
        enabled: true,
        color: '#000000',
        align: 'right',
        x: -10,
        y: 20,
        formatter: function () {
            return this.y;
        },
        style: {
            font: 'normal 13px Verdana, sans-serif'
        }
    }
};
```

And i set values on this way:

```
    var colors = Highcharts.getOptions().colors;        
    var index = 0;
    options.series = [];
    series.data = [];
    for (var i in Data) {
        if (parseInt(Data[i]) != 0) {
            series.data.push({ y: parseInt(Data[i]), color: colors[index]            });
            index++;
        }
        else {
            series.data.push(null);
        }
    }
    options.series.push(series);
    chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for http://jsfiddle.net/YCf9z

you can get this by using

```
pointPadding: 0.1
```

hope this is useful for you

Answer (score 0):

In Highcharts, one series could have only one width, so if you want to have each bar another width, split your data into series and use `pointWidth` to set width.